# Add filter for questions with accepted answers to newest list

Tags: feature-request

When I search for something, let's say C++ and I look at the list of newest questions, I would like to filter out items that already have the answer accepted by the questioner.

Comment: add this `hasaccepted:0` to your search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- Use the 'unanswered' tab instead of the newest. These are not sorted in descending posting date order however.
- Use the search functionality; search for the tagname (in square brackets) plus the `hasaccepted:no` modifier, then sort by newest.

  For your example, that'd be a search for [`[c++] hasaccepted:no`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bc%2b%2b%5d%20hasaccepted%3ano).